# Background Execution of Google Colab Pro+

Tags: google-colaboratory

I am having Google Colab Pro+ subscription and trying to run my notebook in background. But after some time execution halts. As per Description in Google ColabPro+ it supports background execution.

Can some one help?

Thank you

Comment: Did you enable background execution - Runtime -> Change runtime type -> Background execution ?

Answer (score 3):

Click on Runtime option in the top left menu, then click on change runtime type, there you will see a checkbox for Background execution, check it and you can enjoy the benefit of Colab Pro+ :)

Comment: As of 2022-10-03 I don't see an option to check "Background execution" in that dropdown menu. See image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3Lrj.png

Answer (score 3):

Background execution is enabled by default on all Colab Pro+ sessions. I believe they have updated that modal to communicate the new policy
[image]

Comment: I am using this as now, I don't see background execution, despite the claim that it is so.

Answer (score 1):

For future viewers - I am unsure whether this still is the case, or if it now always has background execution enabled; [See this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3Lrj.png) for my current menu under Runtime -> Change runtime type -> Background execution. As far as I know Colab does not mention this? I might be off here.

Comment: did you solve this? I'm having the same menu as yours

Comment: According to the answer by Reza Shirazian, this is due to Background execution now being enabled by default on all Colab Pro+ sessions, as I suspected. So, for me there was not really anything to solve - all my notebooks did work in background execution mode.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into that today, too: You now need Pro+ Subscription for background execution. Colab pro is not enough.