# How to get results from the background execution job in Google Colab Pro Plus?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I am able to run Python scripts in the background with my Google Colab Pro Plus subscription. But how do I retrieve the results from the background execution job?

As an example, I am able to run a ML training job, put my computer in sleep mode, and go to sleep myself. When I wake up next day, I am able to find the saved model weights in my Google Drive. However, I can't find the results of the execution. It seems to me that Colab has saved it somewhere. I need help in figuring out how to retrieve it.

Comment: I have reviewed similar question like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70225487/background-execution-of-google-colab-pro  But it does not address my specific question.